# XY-Scatter Chart In SSRS Won't Display Points

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reporting, graphing

I'm a bit confused with this one.

I have a Dataset with a BackupDate and a BackupTime as well as a BackupType.  The BackupDate is comprised of 12 characters from the left of a datetime string within a table.  The BackupTime is comprised of 8 characters from the right of that same datetime string.  So for example:  BackupDate would be 'December 12 2008' and the BackupTime would be '12:53PM.'

I have added an XY-scatter chart to the report.  I've added a 'series' value for the BackupType (so one can distinguish between a Full/Incr/Log backup).  I've added a category value of BackupDate and set the Scale for the X-axis from the Min of BackupDate to the Max of BackupDate.  I've then added an item to the Values with the Y variable set to BackupTime and the X variable set to BackupDate.  The interval for the Y-axis is 12:00AM to 11:59PM and the formatting for the labels is 'hh:mmtt'.

The BackupTime matches the format of the Y-axis.  The BackupDate matches the format of the X-axis.  10 entries are retrieved by my Dataset and the Legend is properly populated by the BackupType field.

No points are being plotted on the graph and no markers/pointers are shown if they are enabled.  There should be a point on the graph for every point in time of each day there is a backup of a specific type.

Am I missing something?  Does anyone know of a good tutorial dealing specifically with XY-scatter graphs and using them in a way I intend?

I am using the 2005 version of SSRS rather than the 2008 version.

Screenshot of what my chart currently looks like:

[image]

In case it could be dataset related:

```
SELECT     TOP (10) backup_type, LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(backup_finish_date, 
                  12))) AS BackupDate, LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(backup_finish_date, 8))) AS BackupTime
 FROM         DBARepository.Backup_History
```

As requested, here are the results of this query.  There is a Where clause to constrain the results to a specific database of a specific server that was not included in the above SQL Query.

```
Log      Dec 26 2008   12:00PM
Log   Dec 27 2008   4:00AM
Log   Dec 27 2008   8:00AM
Log   Dec 27 2008   12:00PM
Log   Dec 27 2008   4:00PM
Log   Dec 27 2008   8:00PM
Database      Dec 27 2008   10:01PM
Log   Dec 28 2008   12:00AM
Log   Dec 28 2008   4:00AM
Log   Dec 28 2008   8:00AM
```

Answer (score 0):

As the data grows, the scatter chart avoids X-axis values if it extends the (floating/numeric) limitations

Answer (score 0):

Open the chart properties->X-Axis tab->Minor tick mark->Numeric or time-scale values...
It should solve your problem.

Comment: Its been awhile since I touched this (I haven't had any use for it), but I'm pretty sure I remember that using that ended up turning my dates into seconds (no matter which option I used)

Comment: Can you tell how to add custom lines in scatter chart in reporting services